# Restoring TF2 from "steamapps/common/Team fortress 2"

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I spent a month downloading this game and now i lost the backup, I'm left with only the content of the folder mentioned above (hl2.exe etc) is there anyway i can restore this without spending another month of downloading :( :?

I already put it back to common/ folder but steam doesn't recognize it!

when i go into store i get this:
" 
Team Fortress 2 is already in your Steam library"

NVM, fixed, how can i delete this :?

Comment: Have you attempted to "Verfiy local content" after restoring? I've done this before in the past, because I flatten my computers with an alarming frequency. Since you've fixed your problem, please write an answer that describes what you did to fix it, and "accept" the answer. :)

Comment: If you fixed it, please detail how you fixed it, as it will help other people too.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what fixed my problem, but all i did was to close steam, recheck the folder, wait a few seconds, open it again and go to store and find out that it says (already in your library, click here to play) while i saw this there was no tf2 in my game library, it took a few seconds of installing then it showed me that i must download 3GB and I put it to schedule for tonight :) the backup I had is pretty old (when the hooks were just added) so I'm guessing that might be the cause, or just some files can't be moves like that!

Summary:
1. close steam
2. paste your Team Fortress 2 folder to steam/steamapps/common/ 
3. open it and search for your game on store and click play! it will install it again ( if it's not there re open steam after a few seconds )

Comment: As Ohnana mentioned, you should go into the properties for the game and click on "Verify local content" to make sure that you're not missing anything.